# How to merge multiple glb files in Python?

Tags: python, gltf

I'm attempting to merge multiple GLB files in Python using pygltflib, but I don't seem to be able to work out how to do it, as there doesn't appear to be a function to do that.

It looks like it's possible in Node.js (using glTF-Transform:  https://github.com/donmccurdy/glTF-Transform/discussions/691), but everything else I have for this project is in Python.

Is there a library somewhere that I should / could be using for this?

I've tried using the following, but it's not currently working:

```
import os
import pygltflib
import pprint

def get_glb_files(directory):
    glb_files = []
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".glb"):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                glb_files.append(file_path)
    
    return glb_files



def merge_glb_files(gltf_a, gltf_b):
  nodes_count_a = len(gltf_a.nodes)
  materials_count_a = len(gltf_a.materials)
  meshes_count_a = len(gltf_a.meshes)
  accessors_count_a = len(gltf_a.accessors)
  bufferViews_count_a = len(gltf_a.bufferViews)
  buffers_count_a = len(gltf_a.buffers)

  # Adjust all the offsets.

  # Assume there is only one scene
  gltf_b.scenes[0].nodes = [n + nodes_count_a for n in gltf_b.scenes[0].nodes]

  for node in gltf_b.nodes:
    node.mesh += meshes_count_a

  for mesh in gltf_b.meshes:
    for primitive in mesh.primitives:
      a = primitive.attributes
      if a.COLOR_0 != None:
        a.COLOR_0 += accessors_count_a
      if a.JOINTS_0 != None:
        a.JOINTS_0 += accessors_count_a
      if a.NORMAL != None:
        a.NORMAL += accessors_count_a
      if a.POSITION != None:
        a.POSITION += accessors_count_a
      if a.TANGENT != None:
        a.TANGENT += accessors_count_a
      if a.TEXCOORD_0 != None:
        a.TEXCOORD_0 += accessors_count_a
      if a.TEXCOORD_1 != None:
        a.TEXCOORD_1 += accessors_count_a
      if a.WEIGHTS_0 != None:
        a.WEIGHTS_0 += accessors_count_a
      primitive.indices += accessors_count_a
      primitive.material += materials_count_a

  for accessor in gltf_b.accessors:
    if accessor.bufferView:
        accessor.bufferView += bufferViews_count_a
    else:
        accessor.bufferView = bufferViews_count_a

  for bufferView in gltf_b.bufferViews:
    bufferView.buffer += buffers_count_a

  # Now merge the gltfs.
  gltf_b.scenes[0].nodes += gltf_a.scenes[0].nodes
  gltf_b.nodes += gltf_a.nodes
  gltf_b.materials += gltf_a.materials
  gltf_b.meshes += gltf_a.meshes
  gltf_b.accessors += gltf_a.accessors
  gltf_b.bufferViews += gltf_a.bufferViews
  gltf_b.buffers += gltf_a.buffers

  return gltf_b



def combine_gltf_meshes(glb_file_list, session_key):
    current_mesh = None

    # Iterate through each mesh file
    for mesh_file in glb_file_list:
        gltf = pygltflib.GLTF2().load(mesh_file)
        if not current_mesh:
            current_mesh = gltf
        else:
        # Load the glTF file
            current_mesh = merge_glb_files(current_mesh, gltf)

    # Save the combined glTF file
    combined_gltf_file = session_key + '_combined.glb'
    current_mesh.save(combined_gltf_file)

    return combined_gltf_file


def main():
        
    glb_file_list = get_glb_files('./glbs')
    
    session_key = 'test'
    combined_gltf = combine_gltf_meshes(glb_file_list, session_key)
    
    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But that's resulting in getting the same mesh twice, at two different locations:

[Image from glTF Viewer showing two meshes next to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB6zs.png)